# Read from DataGrid not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

I have created a simple datagrid to show some values, let the user change them and read back the changed values in the background program. Here is the XAML design file

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="ButAdd" Content="Add Row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="362,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TeBoResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="52,220,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Display the Row 0 colmn 1 changed value here:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" AcceptsReturn="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="ButRead" Content="Read Row 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="425,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DaGr" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="133" Margin="10,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsManipulationEnabled="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding Path=No, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check box" Binding="{Binding Path=Sel}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Combo box" Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="{Binding Path=Drop}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CoBo_IN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="344,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Visibility="Visible">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Move" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="88"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Dock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="88" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

And the backgroud vb.net code is here

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports DataGrid.datset
Imports System.Windows
Class MainWindow
    Public Property coll As New ObservableCollection(Of bind)()
    Private Sub ButAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButAdd.Click
       Dim qw As New bind()
       qw.No = "Change Me"
       qw.Sel = Nothing
       qw.Drop = CoBo_IN
       coll.Add(qw)
       DaGr.ItemsSource = coll
    End Sub

   Private Sub ButRead_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButRead.Click
        Dim val As String
        For Each item As bind In DaGr.Items
            val = item.No
            TeBoResult.Text = TeBoResult.Text & val
        Next
   End Sub

End Class

Public Class datset : Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
   Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
   Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged


   Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
       RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
   End Sub

   Public Structure bind
       Public Property No As String
       Public Property Sel As Boolean
       Public Property Drop As ComboBox
   End Structure

End Class
```

So When I click on the Add Row button the row with the default contents gets added in the TextColumn and CheckBoxColumn but the ComboBoxColumn dosent display the combo!!(but when I double click inside this cell the ComboBox appears but It is empty). What could be reason for this behaviour?

Next the user will change the contents inside the TextColumn and it gets changed in the GUI as required.

Next when the user clicks on the botton Read Row, all the contents of the TextColumn are read one after the other and is displayed in the Result text box. The problem is though the GUI has a new text when it is read sequentially the **val** variable still shows the previously bound values only. I thought the problem is with TwoWay binding but it seems to be something else.

Why does the read on **DataGrid** dosen't give an updated value?

Comment: One issue is that you're trying to two-way bind to a `struct`. Change it to a `class` if you want writeable properties.

Comment: @Shoe but that structure has the variable of type 'property' which is basically 'get' and 'set' so shouldn't it be read write capable?

Comment: @Shoe Thanks your suggetion worked but the ComboBox is not visible till I go to edit mode and even after getting into edit mode the items of combobox are empty!! any idea why?

Comment: You can write to structs, but it creates a copy of the value being assigned. This obviously breaks binding because your binding doesn't point to the copy. As far as the combobox goes I don't see where you are setting an itemssource for it. It's also not clear why you don't use a `List` type to hold the data for your `DataGridCombobox`

Comment: @Shoe In the XAML file the 'DataGridCombobox' is bound to the 'Path=Drop'. The 'coll' has a property of 'combobox' and I am setting this to an already existing comobobox 'CoBo_IN', so shouldn't the items get bound when we assgin an already existing variable to new one?

Comment: That's not the way it should be done. If you want both comboboxes to have the same items, specify the same itemssource. Forcing a combobox means you can never display that data any other way without jumping hoops.

Comment: @Shoe I added a new `public list` and linked that to the `qw` in the following way `qw.Drop.ItemsSource = list_name`, then as usual added the `qw` to the `coll`. But still I see the ComboBox is empty!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't know to much of VB, but I can see some things here are not ok. For instance `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. Here you must to reference the collection to bind, in this case `coll`. The code should be something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
x:Name="window">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="ButAdd" Content="Add Row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="362,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TeBoResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="52,220,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Display the Row 0 colmn 1 changed value here:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" AcceptsReturn="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="ButRead" Content="Read Row 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="425,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DaGr" ItemsSource="{Binding col, ElementName =window}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="133" Margin="10,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsManipulationEnabled="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding Path=No, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check box" Binding="{Binding Path=Sel, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Combo box" Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="{Binding Path=Drop, Mode=TwoWay"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CoBo_IN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="344,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Visibility="Visible">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Move" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="88"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Dock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="88" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Note the items source binding, and the name of the window, also note the bindings should be two way, for update the source too. This new binding references to the `col` collection. Now in he code behind you shoul not re-set the grid intems source each time you add an item. If the collection is an observable collection then it is added automatically, and now the items should works::

```
Private Sub ButAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButAdd.Click
   Dim qw As New bind()
   qw.No = "Change Me"
   qw.Sel = Nothing
   qw.Drop = CoBo_IN
   coll.Add(qw)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok I tried it out I see that now I dont need to link the 'DataGrid' using the Itemsource, but still the ComboBox Items are empty and when I click the 'Read button' it is still not able to read back from the grid.